# import ply file and rander depth map using nodes

Tags: depth-map

I sucessfully import .ply file using add-on. Now I am trying to get depth map using composting nodes. But I found that the imported ply has no Z channel.
So how can I handle it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the scene to get data from:

[image]